# How to unbox Async<string> []

Tags: f#, jobs, hopac

So I have an `Async<string> []` and for the life of me I can't figure out how to unbox it!

I started with

`Job<Result<string>> []`

Then I managed to get it to

`Job<string> []`

So I added in `Job.toAsync` thinking converting it to an async might be easier to get out. NOPE

Now I have

`Async<string> []`

I'm using the `Hopac` lib

So my question is, how do I just get a `string []`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to somehow *run* those asyncs, so that each returns you a value. The easiest way is to run them in parallel, for there is a built-in function for it - `Async.Parallel`. This function takes a sequence of asyncs and returns an async of an array, which you can then run with `Async.RunSynchronously` or similar:

```
let asyncs : Async<string> [] = ...
let results = asyncs |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Alternatively, if you want them to run sequentially, you could run them one by one and accumulate the result as you go. Unfortunately, there is no built-in function to do it, so you'll have to code it yourself. Something like this:

```
let runEm asyncs =
   let loop rest resultsSoFar = 
      match rest with
      | x::xs -> 
          async {
             let! r = x
             return! loop xs (r:resultsSoFar)
          }
      | [] -> 
          async { return resultsSoFar }

   async {
     let! ress = loop asyncs [] 
     return ress |> List.reverse
   }

// Usage:
let asyncs : Async<string> [] = ...
let results = runEm asyncs |> Async.RunSynchronously
```